# CakePHP 2.3 how to set the paginate order with find_in_set

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'd like to paginate some data and order them using FIND_IN_SET. If there is only one param it works setting the order like so:

```
$this->paginate['order'] = 'FIND_IN_SET(Catalog.pseudonym_id, "197,109,687")';
```

In CakePHP2, when there is more then one order param, they have to be entered as key => value. How can this be done with FIND_IN_SET? The following don't work

```
array(
    (int) 0 => 'FIND_IN_SET(Catalog.pseudonym_id, "197,109,687")',
    'Catalog.catalog_type_id' => 'ASC',
    'Edition.year' => 'asc'
)

array(
    'FIND_IN_SET' => '(Catalog.pseudonym_id, "197,109,687")',
    'Catalog.catalog_type_id' => 'ASC',
    'Edition.year' => 'asc'
)

array(
    'FIND_IN_SET (Catalog.pseudonym_id, "197,109,687")' => 'ASC',
    'Catalog.catalog_type_id' => 'ASC',
    'Edition.year' => 'asc'
)
```

Any ideas? work around?

Answer (score 1):

The way to have it work, is to set the order param as a string and not using the array, and then it's ok, as follow:

```
$this->paginate['order'] = 'FIND_IN_SET(Catalog.pseudonym_id, "197,109,687"), Catalog.catalog_type_id ASC, Edition.year ASC';
```